# Apply pagination, filtering, sorting, projections in repository when using HotChocolate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, graphql, hotchocolate

When looking at the HotChocolate documentation e.g. for projection, the projection is applied on `IQueryable`:

```
public class Query
{
    [UseProjection]
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers([Service] IUserRepository repository)
        => repository.GetUsers();
}
```

However I want to use a repository and the repository should return the final result including pagination, filtering, sorting, projections instead of an `IQueryable`. So code in the end should be something like this:

```
public class Query
{
    [UsePaging]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers([Service] IUserRepository repository)
        // idea: pass on pagination, filtering, sorting, projections to repository,
        // so repository can apply these internally
        // -> a) how to obtain those "properties" from the attributes?
        // -> b) how to apply them in the repository?
        => repository.GetUsers(pagination, filtering, sorting, projections);
}
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Better to start executing query without repository (which is better). Then, if it work, maybe you can find access to this. But it should be some kind of middleware. HC applies everything after executing your method. Anyway debugging may help.

Comment: Have the repository return `IQueryable` with a Unit of Work to scope the `DbContext`. Simple and effective, and still creates a simpler interface to introduce something like a testing mock. The alternative is essentially re-writing what EF already does with expressions and the like that still have to comply with EF specific rules.